# VB.net SendMessage with CB_ADDSTRING unbalance the stack

Tags: windows, vb.net, api, stack

I'm trying to fasten up the loading of one form, which populates several combobox with a big amount of data. I did my best stopping the UI while loading ecc shredding the loading time from 20s to 13s, but still the only bottleneck remaining is loading data into ComboBox which takes about 3-4s each. I did research on the internet and found that using Windows API you can fasten it up a lot more. So I did the code:

```
Private Const CB_ERR As Long = -1
Private Const CB_ADDSTRING As Long = &H143
Private Const CB_SETITEMDATA As Long = &H151

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Int32, lParam As String) As Int32
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Int32, lParam As Object) As Int32

Public Sub AddItem(cmb As ComboBox, Item As Object)
    Dim l As Int32

    l = SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, Item.ToString())
    SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_SETITEMDATA, l, Item)

End Sub
```

Mostly taken from the internet. After I try to debug that, on the CB_ADDSTRING part the program crashes with

> ::SendMessage' has unbalanced the stack

I tried to change several things already, changing the lParam type to IntPtr (or Long) crashes with conversion type error, tried to change lParam as Object to MarshalAs Any but still the same error. At this point I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The parameter types are wrong. You should avoid using any `Declare Function` declarations that you find online as they're mostly designed for VB6. In .NET you should use `DllImport`. The correct declaration can be found here: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html - `wParam` should be `IntPtr`, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message about an unbalanced stack on an API call is almost always the result of using VB6 declarations in VB.NET.  The fact that you're using `Long` in your code pretty much guarantees that that is the case.  Windows API functions deal in 32-bit numbers for the most part.  In VB6, the `Integer` data type was 16-bit and the `Long` data type was 32-bit.  In VB.NET, the `Integer` data type is 32-bit and the `Long` data type is 64-bit.  If you find declarations written for VB6, you need to change all `Long` to `Integer` at the very least.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a different type of error after changing that plus info @Visual Vincent sent.
`InvalidArgument=Value of '0' not valid for 'index'. Parameter Name: index`

Comment: If you no longer get the error message you were asking about then this issue is resolved. If you have another issue, you should create a new question for that, with all the information relevant to that specifically.